# On Browser reload Angular js 2 nested routes component not loading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a routeconfig which creates a child route under a parent component, I noticed that all goes when I use (by clicking a href tag with the routelink set to the child route) a route link to access the nested route, but when I refresh the browser when on the child route or enter the child routelink directly in the browser it fails to load the child component i.e only the parent component loads.

url with issue - localhost:3000/#/dashboard/reservation

My route config is below

Main app component routes to parent component (Dashboard)

```
@RouteConfig([
  ...
  { path: '/dashboard/...', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard}, 
  ...
])

Dashboard component creates child route
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/reservation', name: 'Reservation', component: Reservation , useAsDefault: true},
]);
```

Comment: Where did you add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`? I think you need to provide more information (more code) otherwise it's hard to diagnose. Any concrete error messages?

Comment: I think the issue is the custom route outlet directive I used, it tries to re-authenticate the user on browser refresh and somehow it blocks the child component from loading. The problem does not occur if i use the default route outlet.

Comment: I met the same issues, it coz of the error "ReferenceError: System is not defined" in the console. any luck?

Comment: Same error here....

Answer (score 1):

I had met the same issue but I resolved by using this code inside `<head>` of `index.html`.Its a bug with `APP_BASE_HREF`

```
<base href="/">
<!-- Set the base href -->
<script>document.write('<base href="'+ document.location +'"/>');</script>
```